# С какого сервера подгружаются пакеты Nuget?

Tags: visual-studio-code, nuget

Уже перерыл весь интернет. Реалии таковы что могу работать только в Visual Studio Code. Так вышло) Так вот, при попытке установить пакет Nuget, например-
`dotnet add package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel --version 15.0.4795.1001`
выдает ошибку "NU1301: Не удалось загрузить индекс служб для источника [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json."](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.%22)
При отключении прокси админами все заработало, но оставить мой ПК с отключенными прокси конечно никто не позволит. Поэтому нужно открыть сетевой доступ, вопрос только куда? Уже открыли к  https://api.nuget.org/ - не помогло.
UPD:Выяснилось что доступ блокируется к https://api.nuget.org/ поскольку при обращении не проходит аутентификация пользователя. Разбираюсь дальше.

Comment: наверное надо через wireshark смотреть

Comment: @PavelGridin на работе не получится, так как все установки через админов, а вот с дома можно попробовать посмотреть. Спасибо)

Comment: а админы разве не могут на прокси увидеть, куда запросы идут?

Comment: @PavelGridin попробую их озаботить этим, предыдущий не стал на эту тему заморачиваться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо открыть доступ через прокси к https://*.nuget.org*.